How to show a V-Alert above a V-Dialog
I have a global v-alert that I use to show error messages or info, however in a v-dialog when I try to show the alert its hidden behind it. I've tried using elevation and setting the z-index on the v-dialog.
The desired behavior would be for the v-alert to show on top of the v-dialog
Link to VuetifyPlay
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-dialog v-model="showDialog">
        <v-btn @click="toggleAlert">Click for Alert</v-btn>
      </v-dialog>
      <v-alert v-model="showAlert">I am the alert</v-alert>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const msg = ref('Hello World!')
  const showDialog = ref(true)
  const showAlert = ref(false)
  const toggleAlert = () => {
    showAlert.value = !showAlert.value
  }
</script>



v-dialog when rendered gets nested inside a v-overlay (as seen in the DOM inspector) which is why setting the z-index does nothing.  setting the z-index on v-alert should work though... .v-alert { z-index: 9999 }

I had previously set .v-alert {z-index:1000} which didn't work, but setting it to 9999 as you did solved it. Thank you, if you want to add this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Glad it helped.  Answer posted.

The main issue with setting z-index of the v-dialog is that it is rendered within a v-overlay, meaning v-dialog exists within a different stacking context than the v-alert.
Setting z-index of the v-alert will work though at placing it above the overlay.
v-overlay has a z-index of 2400, so any value greater than that will work.
.v-alert {
  z-index: 2401
}

